# Write a dockerfile for elastic container

Tags: dockerfile

Is there any ready docker image available with this addon already installed?

https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank#installing

If no, what are the steps to write a dockerfile for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added these lines to standard elastic docerfile

```
WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch
RUN pip install requests  elasticsearch==5.5.3
RUN git clone  https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank.git
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank
```

Full code can be checked here...

https://github.com/shantanuo/docker/blob/master/esml/Dockerfile